# Define MongoDB compound keys as one key

Tags: mongodb

is it somehow possible, to define one compound key, consisting of two mongoDB objectID's or numeric types, so to make one key out of it?

This is necessary, because I have lots of participants creating documents which they save into one big collection together, so I cannot be sure, that the MongoDB Object ID for each document is distinct. So I wanted to add some additional key, maybe one userID's number or email or something similar...
maybe 2 ObjectID's

Comment: the permutations and combinations for mongoose `_id` is more than 20 million or far than that... So you do not need worry about its uniquness

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate unique object id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything for your `_id` field. So this is possible:

```
db.collection.insertOne({
    _id: {
        "first": new ObjectId(),
        "second": new ObjectId(),
    }
})
```

The default unique index on the `_id` field also guarantees uniqueness on this kind of field.

However, I would doubt that this is a good solution to your problem as it would probably just defer the underlying problem (which really doesn't exist - kindly see this answer, too: [How to generate unique object id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb)). Instead, I would suggest you have your clients create documents without specifying an `_id` explicitly and let MongoDB create the `_id` (on the server side or on the client side depending on your driver and your settings where client-side generation should be preferred). This will guarantee uniqueness (even when you do sharding).

There always is a unique index on your _id field anyway so to be on the super safe side with respect to run-time behaviour you could put a retrying exception handler in place on the client side for the (pretty much impossible) case that you end up with two identical `_id`s and hence an exception.

Also see this answer: [Mongodb - must _id be globally unique when sharding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334017/mongodb-must-id-be-globally-unique-when-sharding)

Comment: ok, but that's my original question... if the server creates the id's, is it really ensured they are all unique? Imagine, you have 20 million users pushing documents to your server each second, it might be more than one each second, so timestamp is not unique, for the random number, they could repeat, as it is more than 16 million numbers, so that leaves it out to the machine-identifier (e.g ip or mac adress) and process-id, are they really unique or could they also hash to the same values?

Comment: They are guaranteed to be unique by the server (note the last part of the ObjectId structure here): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid and also this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb

Comment: ok thats quite  good to hear, but this only counts for one server... imagine when I have two servers... then I would have to use sharding is that right? because it might happen, that I have to upload all documents one hierarchy above to an aggregator server, where it could clash there...

Comment: "if the server creates the id's" is quite theoretical question. At the moment Id's are created by clients.

Comment: @Alex Blex, I dont understand, why do you think Id's are created by clients? when you are not giving an _id value when client creates a document, and the document is inserted into MongoDB Collection, it gets an _id field created from the server, or not..?

Comment: @user2883596 It's responsibility of the driver to create the Id. Driver runs clientside. https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/b75bcf071a27c8374a8095884560bdae0c65929b/lib/bson/objectid.js#L142 is how it's done in nodejs driver. Check sources of the driver for the language you are using. If you don't provide the Id from the application level, it doesn't mean the Id created by the database. It is created by the library you are using in your application.

Comment: @AlexBlex: That's not correct. You can send documents without the _id field to the server and have the server generate the ObjectId for you. Kindly see e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723954/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-and-server-generated-objectids

Comment: Cheers, @dnickless, indeed there is an option to generate it serverside https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0074ca3ac8171243232d4e037f5150ba48d11bc5/src/mongo/bson/oid.cpp#L135. In this case machine Id and process Id will come from the master node, which won't improve uniqueness, yet still safe enough. The recommended way is to generate it client side: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/pr-KHTMfA3o/8Lg_r-Zmqf8J

Comment: @AlexBlex: Agreed. I also updated my answer which indeed had been bit wonky before. Got a bit confused by the question plus parallel work going on... Lastly, I voted for closing this question because, really, it has been answered in a more generic fashion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId in MongoDb is hexadecimal value.

> ObjectId() Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte
> ObjectId value consists of:
>
> ```
>     4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>     3-byte machine identifier,
>     2-byte process id, and
>     3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
> ```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Hence, the object Id will be uniquely auto-generated when you insert a document.
However, you can make a custom combination of hexadecimal value of length 24, when you insert a document.

For example,

```
1DCD6500 -- this can be custom hex identifier
A98AC7 -- another custom hex identifier
2B67  -- another custom hex identifier
A981CE -- Incremental custom hex identifier
```

Now if you try to insert a document with `_id` as `1DCD6500A98AC72B67A981CE`. The document will be saved.

e.g. `{ "_id" : ObjectId("1DCD6500A98AC72B67A981CE"), "name" : "sample", "personid" : 39 }`

So based on definition of the ObjectId you can make custom ObjectId.
But in that case you will be responsible to make sure **ObjectId is unique**, otherwise the mongodb will throw error

- `"E11000 duplicate key error collection:`